# Format date from standard php format to userdefined style in java

Tags: java, php, android

I am receiving the date format string from a server (eg:"j,n,Y", "d,M,yyyyy", "d de M de Y"  etc). These are user defined and it varies from user to user.

"j,n,Y"  means an output like 1,20,2013
this in java will be "d,M,yyyy"

Does anyone know any solid library to convert date format String in java, which format the String to compatible with SimpleDateFormat?

I mean I will receive "j,n,Y" and after using the function, I need it to be "d,M,yyyy"

for now I'm just using a find and replace

```
....
dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("d","dd");
.... more replaces
....
```

but I know that there are lot of posibilities not contemplated, that's why I'm looking for a better option.

Comment: So you need to do it in Android?? What will be the input string and what output you need?? @Pedro

Comment: well yes I'll need to work on android, for now I'm just using find and replace, but is not safe and there are lot of considerations I'm missing. that's why i'm asking

Comment: So What kind of input string and what output date style you need??@Pedro

Comment: well the imput String is a serverside dateFormat in php compliant with http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php format created by a user. and the ouput string is a SimpleDateFormat format String

Comment: Is that format is predefined??

Comment: nop, each user, can enter whatever it wants on the time format, the only requirment is to be compliant with the php  standard, so in android I receive the same format String used in php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90826/discussion-between-subin-thomas-and-pedro-teran).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90892/discussion-between-pedro-teran-and-subin-thomas).